# How to filter array of objects using one array and create another array? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code

```
 var people = [
          {name:'Sam', age: 22},
          {name:'Pam', age: 24},
          {name:'Adam', age: 25},
          {name:'Sam', age: 26},
          {name:'Pam', age: 28},
          {name:'Pam', age: 26}
  ];

  var nameFilter = ['Sam', 'Pam'];
```

Using names, I want to get corresponding ages

I should get all these values as an array of ages

> [22,26,24,28,26]

I don't want unique values.

What is the the easiest way to achieve this using Vanilla JS. I don't want to use Lodash or Jquery

Comment: What did you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var people = [{name:'Sam', age: 22},
  {name:'Pam', age: 24},
  {name:'Adam', age: 25},
  {name:'Sam', age: 26},
  {name:'Pam', age: 28},
  {name:'Pam', age: 26}
];

var nameFilter = ['Sam', 'Pam'];
var res = people.filter(p => nameFilter.includes(p.name)).map(p => p.age)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this using `filter()` `includes()` and `map()`

```js
var people = [{name:'Sam', age: 22},
          {name:'Pam', age: 24},
          {name:'Adam', age: 25},
          {name:'Sam', age: 26},
          {name:'Pam', age: 28},
          {name:'Pam', age: 26}

  ];

  var nameFilter = ['Sam', 'Pam'];
let ages = people.filter(person => nameFilter.includes(person.name)).map(x => x.age);
console.log(ages);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [{name:'Sam', age: 22},
          {name:'Pam', age: 24},
          {name:'Adam', age: 25},
          {name:'Sam', age: 26},
          {name:'Pam', age: 28},
          {name:'Pam', age: 26}

  ];

  var nameFilter = ['Sam', 'Pam'];

function getValues(array, aname) {
  var tmp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     var obj = array[i];
     for (var j = 0; j < aname.length; j++) {
      var name = aname[j];
      if (obj.name === name) //console.log(obj.age);
        tmp.push(obj.age);
    }
  }
  return tmp;
}

console.log(getValues(people, nameFilter));
```

I did this, tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method of the `Array` type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

And then use `map` to extract the age.

In your example you would do:

```
people
  .filter(e => nameFilter.indexOf(e.name) >= 0)
  .map(e => e.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the more readable approach is the ones suggested already, using both `filter` and `map`. However, if you want to do in one iteration instead two, you can also use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as follow:

```
let ages = people.reduce(
  (acc, {name, age}) => (nameFilter.includes(name) && acc.push(age), acc)
  , []);

console.log(ages); // [ 22, 24, 26, 28, 26 ]
```

Notice that since you have `nameFilter` as array, the Big-O of `includes` can be in the worst scenario O(n); where if you replace it with a plain object you will have O(1). Something like:

```
  let nameFilter = {"Sam": true, "Pam": true};

  let ages = people.reduce(
    (acc, {name, age}) => (nameFilter[name] && acc.push(age), acc)
    , []);
```

And, in case you're interested in both unique values and how many time they're occurring in the original array, you can also change the return value from array to object:

```
  let nameFilter = {"Sam": true, "Pam": true};

  let ages = people.reduce(
    (acc, {name, age}) => (nameFilter[name] && (acc[age] = -~acc[age]), acc)
    , {});

  console.log(ages) // { 22: 1, 24: 1, 26: 2, 28: 1 }
```

In this case you can also quickly check if there is anyone with a certain age, or how many:

```
  var ageInput = "21";
  if (!ages[ageInput]) {
     console.log(`No one ${ageInput} years old!`)
  } else if ages[ageInput] === 1 {
     console.log(`Only one person is ${ageInput} years old`);
  } else {
     console.log(`There are ${age[ageInput]} people that are ${ageInput} years old`)
  }
```

Of course it really depends what you need to do with the obtained data.